# iOS / App Store - Found a bug after submitting for review

Tags: ios, app-store, gamekit

We submitted for review. We got approved. I found a bug that's pretty destructive to our leaderboards. We have a low time leaderboard and the time is submitted for each character and then a total. For some reason, the check was disabled and the total is submitted each time. So of course, we are going to get super low numbers (1/7th of the total) on the board. I know we can prune some of the top number and issue an update. That's all I can think to do.

I know we can patch but users aren't obligated to update.

What would you recommend? Should we patch and wait to launch?

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

So I'm guessing what your question is now, but first off, I have a question: is the app already visible and downloadable for users?

If not, cancel the process, fix the bug and re-upload the app for AppStore-approval.

If it is, then just fix the bug asap and upload the new binary.